# NSBitmapImageRep: Getting the pixel value of an image destroys it

Tags: cocoa, swift

I am trying to get pixel information from a Bitmap file. I have the following code

```
var image: NSBitmapImageRep?
// This image gets initialized here

var pixel_value: Int = 0
image?.getPixel(&pixel_value, atX: 0, y: 0)
// The Debugger shows that the pointer value of image has been changed !
println("First value is: \(pixel_value)")
image?.getPixel(&pixel_value, atX: 0, y: 0)  // Crash here
println("First value is: \(pixel_value)")
```

The program crashes the second time I ask for the value of the pixel. The reason is that the first call to getPixel changed the value of what image points to (one can see in the debugger that the value of image goes from NSBitmapImageRep?  0x00006100000baca0 to NSBitmapImageRep? 0x000000000000006c). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What colorspace has the image? For RGBA you would have to pass an *array* of 4 integers.

Comment: @Martin R: Thanks. That was stupid on my side.